# jquery animate back to original position on scroll DOWN(?)

Tags: jquery, dynamic, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I have searched high and low and can't seem to find answers. I am a jquery novice and I have all animations working correctly on ScrollTop however when I scroll to get back to the top of the page, I would like the one stripe with the text to come back to it's original position. Ive gotten as far as it flickering, so I think Im on the right track. Please help.

Here is the website: www.artdesignstudios.com/prestige/

Here is the script Im working with:

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100){
        $('#stripe1').animate({'width': 0},1000);
    $('#cta1').animate({'left': -100},1000)


    }
    else if ($(window).scrollTop() < 400) {
     $("#stripe1").css({'width':'100%'},800);
     $("#cta1").css('opacity','1');
    }


});

</script>
```

Comment: It would be better to have a `boolean` saying if it has animated or not cause the `else` condition might not work like you expect since < 400 can also be >= 100 and after 400 everything is >= than 100, thats the first step

Comment: Thank you. Can  you show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the main problem of the flickering is that the conditions don't suffice if both cover the same range, which is the case I mentioned in comments.

```
N < 400 can also be >= 100 and after 400 everything is >= than 100
```

For that problem we need to make adjustments for them to cover different ranges of `scroll`, or, use a `boolean var` to make sure the animations will run accordingly to what is expected.
An option is to apply these changes, respecting the different ranges we can test with 150 as `scroll height`:

```
var animated = false;   //added variable to control if stripe was animated
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if (!animated && $(window).scrollTop() >= 150) { //changed
    $('#stripe1').animate({'width': 0}, 1000);
    $('#cta1').animate({'left': -100}, 1000);
    animated = true; //it was animated

  } else if (animated && $(window).scrollTop() < 150) { //changed
    $("#stripe1").css({'width': '100%'}, 800);
    $("#cta1").css('opacity', '1');
    animated = false; //animation ended
  }
});
```

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NgcjS/) to see it in action